# How do I resolve "git pull" merge conflicts onto one of my previous commits?

Tags: git, github

This is what my git tree looks like:

```
A   B   C   D   E
o---o---o---o---o master
         \
          o---o---o---o my_branch
          C1  C2  C3  C4
```

I am trying to rebase my_branch with master, and for my tree to look like this in the end, however, I have merge conflicts, which I want to be resolved as part of my commit C2 (or earlier commit) instead of top of head (C4).

```
A   B   C   D   E
o---o---o---o---o master
                 \
                  o---o---o---o my_branch
                  C1  C2* C3  C4
                       |
                      includes merge conflict resolution with master
```

**Tried: Git rebase & resolve conflict + commit**
`git pull --rebase master` This causes merge conflict.

I can resolve the conflict and do git commit, but, I do not wish to create a new commit, C5. I would rather the conflict changes be made as part of an older commit, say, C2.

**Alternatively, I tried git rebase to C2 followed by git pull**
`git rebase -i C1` Mark C2 as "edit". I hoped to do `git pull --rebase master` on this, and resolve conflicts + commit + `git rebase --continue` so the conflict resolution becomes part of C2, but this did not work.

Can you suggest a way I can do this? Anything short of reverting my changes and re-applying them after git rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You're already replacing all of your commits

Commit `C1` says that its parent commit is `C`.  You need a new and different commit—you might call it `E1`, for instance—that says that its parent is `E`.

This new and different commit will have a new and different hash ID.  In the end, though, you'll still have four commits—they will just be `E1` through `E4`.  Your name `my_branch` will identify new commit `E4`; commit `C4` will be forgotten, and will eventually go away, unless someone or something else has hold of it and won't let go:

```
                  E1  E2  E3  E4
                  o---o---o---o   <-- my_branch
A   B   C   D   E/
o---o---o---o---o   <-- master
         \
          o---o---o---o   [abandoned]
          C1  C2  C3  C4
```

#### When `git rebase` hits a conflict, it stops in the middle of the rebase

Rebase works by copying each commit, one at a time, turning the snapshot in `C1` into a change-set against commit `C`—its parent—and applying that change-set to commit `E`.  Git does this using Git's internal merge engine, i.e., Git also compares `C` vs `E` to determine how to apply `C` vs `C1`.

In this case, that comparison and copy went well, and Git built commit `E1` successfully.  Then Git went on to attempt to build `E2` by comparing `C2` to `C1`, to turn it into a change-set, then merging that with the changes from `C1` to `E1`.  This is where the conflict occurred.  So at this point, you have:

```
                  E1
                  o   <-- HEAD
A   B   C   D   E/
o---o---o---o---o   <-- master
         \
          o---o---o---o   <-- my_branch
          C1  C2  C3  C4
```

Commit `E2` is in progress, but does not exist yet.  You must resolve the conflict, `git add` the resolved files, and run `git rebase --continue` to cause Git to make new commit `E2`:

```
                  E1  E2
                  o---o   <-- HEAD
A   B   C   D   E/
o---o---o---o---o   <-- master
         \
          o---o---o---o   <-- my_branch
          C1  C2  C3  C4
```

At this point Git will be able to attempt to copy `C3`.  If that goes well, Git will make `E3` on its own.  Otherwise it will stop to get your help again, and you go through the same process and eventually use `git rebase --continue` to make Git go on to copy `C4` to `E4`.

Once `E4` is successfully made, there are no copies left to perform, and `git rebase` does its last trick: it moves the name `my_branch` so that it points to `E4` instead of `C4`, re-attaching the special name `HEAD` to the name `my_branch`.